# d3 mousedown event fires, but mouseup event does not fire

Tags: d3.js

I'm seeing some strange behavior in d3. I have a force directed graph in the usual way

```
node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes).enter().append("circle")....
```

and when someone clicks on a node, I want a simple animation (instead of a console.log)

```
function set_focus(d) { console.log('set'); }
function remove_focus() { console.log('remove'); }

node.on("mousedown", set_focus);
node.on("mouseup", remove_focus);
```

Interestingly, when I mousedown on a node, the set event fires, but when I release the mouse, `remove_focus` doesn't fire. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

---

d3v5, chrome 65, macOS 10.13

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/wyv6syzw/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Probably something I should have done myself. I wonder how on earth I'm swallowing that event.... Would you be interested / willing to look at my code?

Comment: There are likely many people that would be willing/interested to look at your code if you can share it publicly.

Comment: @mattbatman the app is at http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/. The code is at  https://github.com/zfrenchee/NN-SVG. I chose to put it all in a single html file -- hope you'll excuse that :]

Comment: important lines are these: https://github.com/zfrenchee/NN-SVG/blob/master/index.html#L414-L429

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tldr: the zoom event is conflicting with your mouseup event.

I created a fork because I'm not too sure what you're going to want to do with this and I didn't want to mess with your git history: [this link is the fork](https://github.com/mattbatman/NN-SVG).

It seems that your Zoom event on the SVG is "consuming" all other events once the mouse is clicked. My impression is that this is a known and commonly complained about issue. I think that this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2887) is related, and so is [this one](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/66#issuecomment-255175895). Per Mike Bostock,

> This is the expected behavior. Per the release notes: “The zoom
>   behavior now consumes handled events.” So, if a mouseup event was part
>   of a zoom gesture, then the zoom behavior stops the immediate
>   propagation of that mouseup event preventing other listeners from
>   receiving it (and where possible prevents the associated browser
>   default behavior). This makes it easier to combine zooming and
>   dragging as in this example:
>
> http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3127661b6f13f9316be745e77fdfb084
>
> If you want to prevent a zoom gesture from starting, use zoom.filter
>   to ignore certain events, or use event.stopPropagation or
>   event.stopImmediatePropagation to prevent the zoom behavior from
>   receiving the initiating event. If you want to do something after a
>   zoom gesture, listen to the zoom event.

I can get your `mouseup` event to fire by either deleting the `d3.zoom` event, or by calling `d3.event.stopPropagation` within the `set_focus` function. So, the two lines below (and in the fork) get your `remove_focus` function to fire, but I'm not sure if I also messed up how you want the zoom event to be working:

```
function set_focus(d) {
    console.log('set');
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    node.style("opacity", function(o) { return (d == o || o.layer == d.layer - 1) ? 1 : 0.1; });
    link.style("opacity", function(o) { return (o.target == d.id) ? 1 : 0.02; });
}

function remove_focus() {
    console.log('remove');
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    node.style("opacity", 1);
    link.style("opacity", function () { return edgeOpacity; })
}
```

Comment: ! Thanks for getting to the bottom of this. Out of curiosity, how did you figure this out? I really need to level up my javascript debugging. Your fix works and I've added a bounty to the question to thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I just came up with a few ideas as to what could be causing the the problem, and tried to test each one. I guessed that either: 1) the event wasn’t getting attached to each node 2) something was getting placed on top of the node in the DOM so the event couldn't be detected or 3) another event was interfering with it. At one point, I logged something from every event in the code so I could see what was firing and what wasn’t. I noticed that the zoom event was firing repeatedly when I clicked and held the mouse. I commented out that bit of code, and the mouseup event worked.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have a listener for the end of a zooming event [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352699/binding-to-zoom-ending-with-the-zoom-behavior)

so you could do something like

`d3.zoom().on('end', remove_focus)`